# Font different in MS Edge than Chrome for PDF when using PDFBox

Tags: java, internet-explorer, pdfbox

I have a PDF template created in Acrobat Reader DC which contains a field that I trying to fill with some text. The field has a specific font that I want to keep. I am able to obtain the field and change the value.

However, when I open the PDF in Internet Explorer the font is a default font. The confusing part is that if I open it in Chrome then it shows the correct font. Not sure why that is, any help is appreciated. I am using PDFBox version 2.

(The font works if I don't use Java to edit the file, if I just manually change it inside Acrobat and save the file then it shows correctly.)

See below for the code used.

```
File file = new File("PDFToReadFrom.pdf");
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(file);

PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = pdDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();

for(PDField pdField : pdAcroForm.getFields()){
    pdField.setValue("value");
}

pdDoc.save(new File("test.pdf"));       
pdDoc.close();
```

Comment: Please upload the source PDF file and link to it. A possible cause is that the PDFToReadFrom.pdf file uses a non standard 14 font and doesn't embed it. Try to change that in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Also tell what PDFBox version you are using, hopefully 2.0.13.

Comment: Internet explorer doesn't have a PDF viewer. Could it be you mean MS Edge?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you for taking your time to respond to my issue. Will respond to your comments in order:
1. I'm afraid I cannot share the content of the PDF file.
2. I am using PDFBox 2.0.13.
3. Yes, I meant MS Edge.

Comment: Please try to reproduce the problem with a public file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you'd better to compare the PDF file (Use Java edited file and the Acrobat generated file), whether they are using the same font.

According to [this article](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithfonts.html), it seems that we could set the font when using PDFBox to create a PDF file.

Comment: The op fills in forms. You create regular page content. Those two are completely different things.